# How To Extract Data From a Login Site

Tags: web-scraping, extract

I'm trying to figure out how to take live data from one site and have it displayed on my site. I would like to do so, where the data updates as it updates on the original site. My theme is sports gaming and my site is structured like ESPN. I would like to grab all the team standings and players stats.

Sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to **scrape** a website and display it in yours, possibly in a better way.

So I would recommend to use [KIMONO](https://www.kimonolabs.com/), Its an web scraping service, which will provide you with the api to get the data in a proper Model.

Check it out, IT should get your job done.

If not you can create your own **scraper** in PHP [(PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)  or Javascript, there are libraries in Javascript also.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!